# Convert complex Java object to Json using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using GSON to serialize Java object.

I have a Java class with following properties.

```
String property1;
Map<String, HashMap> property2 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> property3 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String[]> property4 = new HashMap<>();
```

I want to convert this to Json. Because of the maps with HashMaps inside, it has become difficult. I know I can get Json of a map with `gsonObject.toJson(map)`. But I want all these properties in the Json Object. (all in one. not Concatenating many objects)

Can anyone help me to get this done?

Comment: What type of `HashMap` in your `property2`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it is of <String, Integer> type.

Comment: It cannot be. `<String, int>` is not legal. You probably mean `<String , Integer>`. Also, such a set of embedded collections smells fishy...

Comment: @fge. Yes it is Integer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see what the problem is. Gson can serialize `Map`s just fine.

Assuming your class is named `Test`

```
Test test = new Test();

test.property1 = "some value";

HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("one", 1);
map.put("fourty two", 42);
test.property2.put("property2-key", map);

ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("string1",
            "string2", "string3"));
test.property3.put("property3-key", strings);

String[] stringArray = { "array1", "array2", "array3" };
test.property4.put("property4-key", stringArray);

Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(test);
System.out.println(json);
```

It generates the following

```
{
    "property1": "some value",
    "property2": {
        "property2-key": {
            "fourty two": 42,
            "one": 1
        }
    },
    "property3": {
        "property3-key": [
            "string1",
            "string2",
            "string3"
        ]
    },
    "property4": {
        "property4-key": [
            "array1",
            "array2",
            "array3"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: The property2 is of type Map<String, HashMap>. The HashMap inside it is of <String, Integer>.

Comment: @harsh That is not a problem.

Comment: It works only for simple Maps. Does not work for Maps inside Maps.

Comment: @harsh If you look at the generated JSON, you have a map inside a map in `property2`. `property2` is a `Map` and it contains a key `property2-key` which has a value that is a `Map`.

Comment: It gives an error to me starting with
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument is not an array
 at java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(Native Method)
 at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter.write(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:91)
 at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
 at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:209)

Comment: @harsh You'll have to show us what you are doing. Edit your question and add it below.

Comment: I did it. I had done a mistake earlier. Thank you friend. I have another problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22441134/jsonobject-add-property-maps can you see that please. I want to do in that way too