# JsonObject add property - maps

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a class called Test with a `String id` field and a `HashMap map` like  `Map<String, String[]>`, `Map<String, ArrayList<String>>`, and `Map<String, HashMap>` (Here the second `HashMap` is a `<String, Integer>` one) I have the following code.

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();

jsonObject.addProperty("id", test.getId);
```

Like this, I want to add the Map to this. Adding like `jsonObject.addProperty("map", String.valueOf(test.getMap()));` does not do the work properly as it add "(commas) to beginning and end. Can somebody tell me what is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`JsonObject` has `add` method to add primitives, but only a single `add` method to add complex types. This method expects a `JsonElement` so that's what you have to create.

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonElement jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(test.getMap());
jsonObject.add("map", jsonElement);
```

I don't know exactly why you're doing this. In your last question, I showed you how to generate full JSON from the `Test` class.

You can use

```
gson.toJsonTree(test);
```

to get the JSON as a `JsonElement`, which you can cast to a `JsonObject`.